# Set data-bind from Checkbox

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui

```
    <input type="hidden" name="OPTIONAL">

    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="checkbox" name="OPTIONAL" id="ValueCheck" onclick="setCheckedValue()" />
    </div>



    <script type="text/javascript">

        function setCheckedValue()
        {
            if (document.getElementById("ValueCheck").checked)
            {
                document.getElementsByName("OPTIONAL")[0].value = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                document.getElementsByName("OPTIONAL")[0].value = 0;
            }        
        };
    </script>
```

Hello,

I have this hidden binded to a Model in my ascx.
I need to set the value of the hidden to 1 when checkbox is cheked and 0 when it's not.

The problem is that the hidden uses data-bind="value:OPTIONAL" as value and the value="..." 
setted by my checkbox is useless.

What can I do to set the data-bind value from my checkbox?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

From your if condition i'm guessing you try to set your hidden input value depending on the combobox, if it's checked set it to 1 otherwise 0.

- Instead adding name (i'm not sure why you use it, when you have data-bind) use **data-bind**

> The problem is that the hidden uses data-bind="value:OPTIONAL" as
>   value and the value="..." setted by my checkbox is useless.

- i don't really get what this mean, but insted use **checked** to get checkbox value

Try this code :

```
  <div id="example">
    <input type="hidden" data-bind="value:text">
    <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: isChecked, click:clicked" />
    <button data-bind="click: seeValue" >see hidden texbox value</button>
  </div>
  <script>
  var viewModel = kendo.observable({
      isChecked: 1,
      text: 1,
      clicked: function(e){
        this.isChecked ? this.set("text",1) : this.set("text",0);
      },
      seeValue: function(e){
        alert(this.text);
      }
  });


  kendo.bind(document.getElementById("example"), viewModel);
```

> [DEMO](http://dojo.telerik.com/aDIjI)

**note**: you can check/uncheck the checkbox first then click the button to see the hidden input value